# Wifi connected but no internet on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. Despite being connected to the wifi, there is no internet. If I try to ping a server, I get no answer.

I googled **extensively** for a solution, without finding anything that works for me. I know that similar questions have been asked several times already, but nothing worked.

**Important notes:**

- My laptop works just fine with other WiFis
- This WiFi works just fine with other devices
- I have never had this problem before
- Turning off and back on WiFi on my laptop doesn't work
- Forgetting network doesn't work
- Restarting my laptop doesn't work
- Restarting modem doesn't work

**Update:**

I still have this problem, it appears randomly.

If i run nmcli when connected to the WiFi I get this:

```
nmcli
wlp3s0: connected to CenturyLink2002
        "Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN)"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 74:E5:0B:B0:9E:B6, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.0.46/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.0.0/24
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        inet6 fe80::695c:c596:311c:929f/64
        route6 ff00::/8
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 fe80::/64

enp10s0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
        ethernet (r8169), 84:8F:69:C7:AD:32, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.0.1 205.171.3.25
        domains: Home
        interface: wlp3s0

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(5) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

Comment: What does `nmcli` show when connected to your router?

Comment: I 've been at work all day and now I've just come back and now it works again. Very weird. I will update with further details if it happens again.

Comment: Your laptop just forget it shouldn't work at home).

Comment: I still have this problem, I updated the question.